# Is working with a remote repository (fetch/push) requires a REMOTE TRACKING branch to exist?

Tags: git

I am new to Git.

I know that Git remote repos are used for sharing code.

In addition, There are several branches types:

```
1. local. 

    1.1 non-tracking.

    1.2 tracking.

2. remote.
```

In order to share a code, I need to "push" that code from my local repository to the remote repository.

Assume I:

- created a remote repo on Github. This remote repo is currently empty.
- Local machine -> Created an alias named "origin" in my local machine so I can interact with that remote repo.
- Local machine -> created a NON-TRACKING branch named "master" using this command:

  git branch *branch-name*.
- Local machine -> I have already made some commits in that non-tracking branch.
- Pushing code will update the remote tracking branch (local machine) and remote branch to be the same as the tracking branch (local machine).
- Fetching code will update the remote tracking branch (local machine) to be the same as the remote branch. Then, an extra merge is required to make the "tracking branch" (local machine) to be the same as the "remote tracking branch" (local machine).

Suppose I want to push/fetch DIRECTLY from the remote branch, without having the REMOTE TRACKING branch (local machine) i.e without having it as the middleman...

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `REMOTE TRACKING branch (local machine)` is not a middleman, it is just a reference to remote branch (hash value in file). You can't change remote branch on your local machine. The changes you do stored in your local branch.

Comment: Hi. I did not say I want to change remote branch. All I asked is if I can interact with the remote branch directly and not via the remote tracking branch (origin/master)?

Comment: Oh, do you use `fetch` command than `merge origin/mester`? If so, you can just use `pull` comand. From [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull): `Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch. In its default mode, git pull is shorthand for git fetch followed by git merge FETCH_HEAD.`

Comment: `fetch` command just receives data from remote repo, as I know, you can't interact with remote branch without that step, but `pull` command do it for you. Reference to remote branch always exists anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose I want to push/fetch DIRECTLY from the remote branch, without having the REMOTE TRACKING branch (local machine) i.e without having it as the middleman...

You're looking at it as if branches were some heavyweight thing.  They aren't, not even, um, remotely.  You push and fetch commits and whatever objects go with them.  Then you hang teeny little labels on the interesting ones. The cost of attaching labels during a fetch or push isn't just negligible, it's barely even discernible.

That said, yes, you can do some pretty flexible refname rewriting.  To play with it, you can use your own repo as a remote, its name is `.`

```
git ls-remote .

git fetch . +refs/heads/*:refs/duplicated-by-fetch/*

git fetch . +refs/*:refs/fetched/*

git push . +refs/fetched/*:refs/pushed/*/original
```

So to directly duplicate all of a remote's refs:

```
git fetch u://r/epo +refs/*:refs/*
```

which git is likely to complain about if one of the copied refs already exists and you've got it checked out; rewriting that is effectively an implicit `git reset --soft`, not something you want invoked unwittingly.

---

The default fetch refspec for a remote is configurable as `remote.$remotename.fetch`, its default is

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```